# Can a user log into a Windows domain on a Win7 workstation before the network drivers come up?

Tags: windows-7, domain, login-script

I have a user who uses a pretty high end 3D package called Virtual Gibbs.  Just last month I built him a new super fast computer with an SATA 6G/s SSD.  For some odd reason when the user first logs on in the morning the login script doesn't run (I should say the machine is authenticating on a Windows 2008r2 domain.)  If he wait a few minutes after booting before logging in then the login script runs fine.  I'm assuming that somehow the login process is being loaded in the OS before the network drivers?  Maybe because of the speed of the SSD?  Is there anyway to make Windows 7 wait for the network to come up before it allows the user to login and initiate a non-existent login script?

Thanks

Comment: `I am assuming`... that is dangerous. :)  Check the log files (event viewer). Does it have a *can not find $something on $network* at login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a GPO setting under Computer Configuration|Administrative Templates|System|Logon called "Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon", which turns off Fast Logon Optimization, which I believe is relevant for Windows 7 (this GPO setting has been around since at least W2K3 and was intended for Windows XP clients). Enable this GPO setting in an appropriate GPO and see if it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in your title: Yes, it is possible to login without network connectivity, if the user has been logged in on the computer at least once with contact to the AD.